# EntityFramework Core 2.0 - Add Migration error "The EntityFramework package is not installed"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

*I'm getting an error when trying to Add-Migration for Entity Framework Core, to a Code First project, here are the details...*

I have created a new ASP.Net Core web project (Core 2.0 in VS 2017).  It's using Microsoft.AspNetCore.All dependency, shown below:

[image]

I am looking to utilize the Entity Framework Core (my understanding was that the All metadata had the EF Core dependencies included already, shown below, looks to be correct):

[image]

I've setup my entities and context and I've ensured the DB is setup using the following code.

**Example Model**

```
public class City
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(200)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Example Context**

```
public class CityInfoContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PointOfInterest> PointsOfInterest { get; set; }

    public CityInfoContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs Config**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc()
    .AddMvcOptions(options => {
        options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        if (options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver != null)
        {
            var res = options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver as DefaultContractResolver;
            res.NamingStrategy = null;
        }
    });

    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddSingleton<IMailService, LocalMailService>();

    // Entity Framework services.
    var connectionString = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=CityInfoDB;Trusted_Connection=True;";
    services.AddDbContext<CityInfoContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
```

Initializing the dB context with this line in my controller:

```
public class DummyController: Controller
{
    CityInfoContext _ctx;

    public DummyController(CityInfoContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
}
```

I can see the db is created successfully - all good so far.

[image]

I want to take a snapshot of my db using this command:
*PM> Add-Migration CityInfoInitialMigration*

But get the error:
*The EntityFramework package is not installed on project 'CityInfo.API'.*

[image]

Has anyone come across this before?  I explicitly tried adding the EF packages but that didn't work either!

Comment: It looks like the EF6 PMC commands are running... What does `Get-Module` say is loaded?

Answer (score 19):

```
NPM> Get-Module
```

If the result contains `EntityFramework`

```
ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands                                                                                                                                                                                         
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------                                                                                                                                                                                         
Script     6.0.0.0    EntityFramework                     {Add-    EFDefaultConnectionFactory, Add-EFProvider, Add-Migration, Enable-Migrations...}                                                                                                                    
Script     2.0.0      EntityFrameworkCore                 {Add-Migration, Drop-Database, Enable-Migrations, Get-DbContext...}                                                                                                                                      
Script     2.0.0.0    NuGet                               {Add-BindingRedirect, Find-Package, Get-Package, Get-Project...}                                                                                                                                         
Script     0.0        profile
```

Meaning both `EntityFrameworkCore` and `EntityFramework` Nuget packages are installed in a project and that causes

> The EntityFramework package is not installed

In my case, I was referencing some Nuget package which was referencing `EntityFramework 6.0.0` (so `EntityFramework` package was referenced **indirectly**). After removing that package, the error was fixed.

The easiest way to find such reference is using `Search Solution Explorer` dialog

[image]

Comment: Extending on from this, if you have both EntityFramework and EntityFrameworkCore modules installed, you can specifiy which module you would like to execute the "add-Migration" command with by specifying: `EntityFrameworkCore\Add-Migration <Migration-Name> -Project <ProjectName> -StartupProject <StartUpPRojectName> -Context <DbContext-Name>`

Comment: @TristanvanDam nice addon Tristan

Comment: @TristanvanDam Thanks. This is annoying with .NET Core 3.0 I am having to do EntityFrameworkCore\ before all migrations and updates to the database. I do not have EntityFramework installed. When I attempt to remove package through the CLI it says it doesn't exist. There is a reference though in AssemblyReferenceCache that seems to be coming from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework or EntityFramework.SQLServer, do you know why VS thinks EntityFramework is installed? Is this a .NET Core 3.0 issue?

Comment: @tchelidze To complete your steps in my case, visual studio must be restarted to clean the cache of the conflicted Entity Framework version. Thank you...

Comment: Running Get-Modules shows i have both installed like your 1st image above (ef v6.0.0 & ef.core 3.1.0 ) I cant find any ef v6 packages in Dependencies and I cant run Unistall-Package on ef v6 I get 'Entity Framework could not be found' error - when I run Add-Migration test, I get the message 'Both EF Core & EF 6 are installed.' Then I run Update-Database and I get SQLite error'table AspNetRoles' already exists. Any pointers how I can remove ef6? Thanks

Comment: @TinoMclaren have you tried searching `EntityFramework` in solution explorer search bar?

Comment: Thank you, ive 'just' done it! ef6 was in another Project of the solution. Im still getting AspNetRoles already exists error though, about to look through the migrations to see whats going on.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package installed. This package defines the PMC commands for EF Core.

Answer (score 4):

1. Cleaned the project
2. Closed down Visual Studio
3. Reopen and ran the "add-migration" again and the error disappeared

Comment: Yeah, shotgun solutions may help, or not. They don't give much insight on what was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

In My Case, I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Answer (score 1):

What i did was i removed all the packages, then did a fresh install and the i restarted visual studio and was good to go